# Why is my query slow to fetch records with a large offset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query to fetch records by page number as follow,

```
SELECT
   FirstName = R.FirstName,
   LastName = R.LastName,
   CountryId = R.CountryID,
   ......
FROM Resource AS R
WHERE ...
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
OFFSET 10 * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The total number of records is over 30,000.

- When `@PageNumber = 1`, the running time is less than 1s, almost instantly.
- When `@PageNumber = 500`, the running time is about 4s.
- When `@PageNumber = 1000`, the running time is less than 12s.
- When `@PageNumber = 2000`, the running time is less than 20s.
- When `@PageNumber = 3000`, the running time is less than 28s.

I wonder why it is much slower to fetch records with large offset than smaller ones, because the total number of fetched rows is the same (10). It looks like the query fetches front records much faster than those that sit behind. Or is there something wrong in the query?

Comment: Did you look at execution plan? What does it say?

Answer (score 5):

As the docs states [Offset Fetch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) (bold emphasis mine):

> ```
> OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }
> ```
>
> **Specifies the number of rows to skip,** before starting to return rows 
>       from the query expression. The argument for the OFFSET clause can be an integer 
>       or expression that is greater than or equal to zero. You can use ROW 
>       and ROWS interchangeably.

Which means all rows will be fetched but skipped for the number of rows that you pass as arguments. So more lines, more time. Simple as that.

Comment: Agree. I think the questioner is confusing work SQL Server has to do on its end, with what is sent over the wire. How could it skip N results without figuring out the first N results? `OFFSET` seems to be in the same spirit as `ORDER BY` -- a way to do lite report formatting instead of using a "real" tool like SSRS. If you need some concept of jumping quickly to the Nth element of some ordinality, you need to figure out a way to express that in an index.